# Google Analytics Reporting API query by ids

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I have an array of post ids, and i need to query the stats for each one. Idealy in 1 query.

My Plan:
In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterSyntax), filters can have AND and OR. I was thinking of adding parentheses in filters.

What i Want:

```
"filters" => 
"
(ga:eventAction==view;ga:eventLabel==post);
(ga:dimension3==10,ga:dimension3==23,ga:dimension3==2,...)
"
```

The Query:

```
return $service->data_ga->get(
      TABLE_ID,
      $start_date,
      $end_date,
      'ga:totalEvents', // metrics
      array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:dimension3',
        'sort' => 'ga:dimension3',
        'filters' => 'ga:eventAction==view;ga:eventLabel==post' // problem
      ));
```

ga:dimension3 is the post id. and i need to return the clicks and views of each one. I realize i can just request all the posts but that could result in a very big query when i only really need 10-20 posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in the query is that you use dimensions in the filtering that you don't query in the first place (event Action, Label). You can use the filter in custom dimension even better using regular expressions eg `ga:dimension3=~(3|10|etc)`.

Comment: for my need the regex was: ga:dimension3=~(^(3|10|etc)$)